# code execute but not inserting data (php)

Tags: php, sql, forms, pdo, sql-insert

hi friends from all over the worlds, i went trough many solution in stack but halas i'm still failing at inserting my data.

my php version is 5.5.12

and here is the code of the insert:

```
   $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `abonne`
    (
    NOM_ABONNE,
    PRENOM_ABONNE,
    ADRESSE_ABONNE,
    VILLE,
    CODE_POSTAL,
    MONTANT_CAUTION,
    ABONNEMENT,
    DATE_PAIEMENT
    )
    VALUES 
    (
    :NOM_ABONNE,
    :PRENOM_ABONNE,
    :ADRESSE_ABONNE,
    :VILLE,
    :CODE_POSTAL,
    :MONTANT_CAUTION,
    :ABONNEMENT,
    :DATE_PAIEMENT,
    );");

    $query->execute([
        array(
        ':NOM_ABONNE'=>$NOM_ABONNE,
        ':PRENOM_ABONNE'=>$PRENOM_ABONNE,
        ':ADRESSE_ABONNE'=>$ADRESSE_ABONNE,
        ':VILLE'=>$VILLE,
        ':CODE_POSTAL'=>$CODE_POSTAL,
        ':$MONTANT_CAUTION'=>$MONTANT_CAUTION,
        ':ABONNEMENT'=>$ABONNEMENT,
        ':DATE_PAIEMENT'=>$DATE_PAIEMENT,
        )
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot?  Does the table exist?  Do the columns exist?  Do all your variables have the data you expect at runtime? Does the query work on it's own (outside of your php)? There's really nothing else we can help you with until you provide some context

Comment: I don't know if this can explain everything, but you have an extra $ on the token: $ MONTANT_CAUTION => $MONTANT_CAUTION